# print the items of an array list in a textfile

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i create an `array list` and i want to print the content of the arraylist in a text file.

The programm take the values from the textboxes and store it in an arraylist and with the 
add button,i want to store it in the text file in given location..

i  am using  Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {

     private ArrayList StoreItems;


    public Form1()
    {
        this.StoreItems = new ArrayList();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    //add button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Make sure an item is complete before adding it to the inventory
        if (this.textBox1.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a code");
            this.textBox1.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (this.textBox2.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must provide the name of the item");
            this.textBox2.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (this.textBox3.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must provide the name of the supplier");
            this.textBox3.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (this.textBox4.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter the price per unit");
            this.textBox4.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (this.textBox5.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter the number of the required products");
            this.textBox5.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (this.textBox6.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter the number of the current stock level");
            this.textBox6.Focus();
            return;
            //string csl = this.textBox6.Text;
        }



        string inValue1, inValue2, inValue3, inValue4, inValue5, inValue6;
        inValue1 = textBox1.Text;
        inValue2 = textBox2.Text;
        inValue3 = textBox3.Text;
        inValue4 = textBox4.Text;
        inValue5 = textBox5.Text;
        inValue6 = textBox6.Text;

      /*  string result = (inValue1 + " " + inValue2 + " " + inValue3 + " "
            + inValue4 + " " + inValue5 + " " + inValue6);  */

        string result=(inValue1+inValue2+inValue3+inValue4+inValue5                    +inValue6);
        StoreItems.Add(result);



        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\v\Desktop\text.txt", Environment.NewLine + result);

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: ArrayList is a legacy class, from the days before .net supported generics. You should avoid it in favor of a generic List<T>, or, in this case, a List<string>

Comment: Please remove all the code that doesn't have anything to do with your question.  You have a lot of stuff there and it's hard to know what part you want us to look at.  Those empty methods are too distracting.

Comment: Also, what exact version of .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of .Net?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    private TextBox[] TextBoxes = {textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6};

    private List<string> storeItems = new List<string>();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        {
            textBox.BackColor = Color.FromName("LightSalmon");
            MessageBox.Show("This item cannot be left blank");
            textBox.Focus();
            return;
        }
        textBox.BackColor = Colors.FromName("Window");
        buffer.Append(textBox.Text);
    }

    var result = buffer.ToString();
    storeItems.Add(result);
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\v\Desktop\text.txt", Environment.NewLine + result);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i still have a problem it hits me an error for the textBoxes in this line:    foreach(var textBox in textBoxes)

Comment: Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express

Comment: could anyone help me with this problem?it hits me an error for the textBoxes in this line: foreach(var textBox in textBoxes)

Comment: @leko there's a typo in my code. I could fix it, but it sounds like you need some practice -- finding that typo is something I'd expect a first year student to be able to do.

Comment: i just start to learn programming.yes,i need practice.thank you again.

Comment: if you want fix it,i can't find it.

Comment: @leko I'll give you a hint: C# is case sensitive